# c# and wpf - how to change comboBox item when select item of another comboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selecteditem

I have an issue with two comboBoxes in wpf. The first and second comboBoxes have the same values of items like here:

**ComboBox1:**
Toyota
Golf
Mini

**ComboBox2**:
Toyota
Golf
Mini

So when I select an item "Toyota" of ComboBox1, I want ComboBox2 to automatically change value of this selected item and vica versa. How to do this in C#? Or should I bind comboBox1 to ComboBox2? I never do it before. Your code would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both `ComboBox` controls share same collection of items then on both of them set [`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx) to `True`

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ... />
```

so for example it can look like this:

```
<StackPanel xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
   <StackPanel.Resources>
       <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="CarList">
           <sys:String>Toyota</sys:String>
           <sys:String>Golf</sys:String>
           <sys:String>Mini</sys:String>
       </x:Array>
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{StaticResource CarList}"/>
   <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{StaticResource CarList}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: @dkozi I tried your code. It is not working. Look here:   <ComboBox Name="cmdCarList" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Height="35" SelectionChanged="cmdCarList_SelectionChanged"/>

 <ComboBox Name="cmdCarListAdd" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Height="35" SelectionChanged="cmdCarListAdd_SelectionChanged">

Comment: @user235973457, how do you define items? I don't see binding to `ItemsSource`

Comment: @user235973457, I've updated my answer with example which works. Both `ComboBox` controls must share one collection

Comment: I use C# to add items of both comboBoxes like ComboBox1.Items.Add("Toyota"); and ComboBox2.Items.Add("Toyota"); in a loaded wpf form

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! but how to get these values in C# if selected items?

Comment: Just like you did before only each `ComboBox.SelectedItem` will be simple `string` showing `Toyota`, `Golf` or `Mini`